# Setting SMTP details for php mail () function

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have been looking for an answer and tried many things to this problem.

My script works fine on my webhost but when moving it to an other dedicated server the mail never gets delivered. Now i need to set the SMTP server but don't get it right.

Using Gmail apps btw. This is how the code looks like.

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

$email = $_POST['email'];


//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i', $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
if(!eregi("@",$email )){
    $error.="Invalid email address entered";
    $errors=1;
}
if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
    $values = array ('name','email','telephone','message');
    $required = array('name','email','telephone','message');

    $your_email = "xxx@example.com";
    $email_subject = "New Messag: ".$_POST['subject'];
    $email_content = "New message:\n";

    foreach($values as $key => $value){
      if(in_array($value,$required)){
        if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'telephone') {
          if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
        }
        $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
      }
    }

    if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
        echo 'Message sent!'; 
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}

$mail->Mailer = "smtp";  
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";  
$mail->Port = 465;  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication  
$mail->Username = "user@gmail.com"; // SMTP username  
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password 

?>
```

So how do i set the SMTP settings right?

Comment: check out this a perfect working soultion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page

Answer (score 8):

***Under Windows only:*** You may try to use [`ini_set()` function<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/ini_set) for the [`SMTP`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/SMTP) and [`smtp_port`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/smtp_port) settings:

```
ini_set('SMTP', 'mysmtphost'); 
ini_set('smtp_port', 25);
```

Comment: how to set username , password and encryption type in it,

Comment: Perfect. Its working fine.. Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 2):

Check out your php.ini, you can set these values there.

Here's the description in the php manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

If you want to use several different SMTP servers in your application, I recommend using a "bigger" mailing framework, p.e. [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: I have the right settings there. But still dossent work. Its a simple form so i think php mail function is the best way to go this time.

Comment: There are a few details involved in the SMTP handshakes (with/without authentication and such), php mail doesn't know them all. For simple tasks the build-in php mail is a good and fast way to solve issues at hand, but keep in mind it has its limits.

Comment: All right, but in my code on the last lines i have set the settings that is requierd by google. But since im using an external smtp server for send mail to the given email adress do i need to change something in php.ini maybe?

Comment: In php.ini, the following parameters are of interest here: smtp_server, smtp_port, auth_username and auth_password. Maybe enable error_logfile and debug_logfile, they might give you additional informations of whats not right here.

Answer (score 0):

Try from your dedicated server to telnet to smtp.gmail.com on port 465. It might be blocked by your internet provider