# Can someone help me edit my code so that it will use SMTP authentication to send mail?

Tags: php, smtp, mailer

Here's my code and it works well, but i don't want it to be sending as normal. I want it to be sending using SMTP authentication. I really do not know how to do that.

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_POST['to_emails'],$_POST['from_email'],$_POST['replyTo'],$_POST['comp_name'],$_POST['subject'])) {

    $failure=true;
    echo "Oops, insufficent mailing values posted";
}else{
    foreach(explode(",",$_POST['to_emails']) as $index=>$email){
        $email=trim($email);

        $compname = $_POST['comp_name'];
        $fromail = $_POST['from_email'];
        $headers = 'From: ' . $compname . ' <' . $fromail .'>';
        $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
        $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: " . $_POST['replyTo'];
        $headers .= "\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $message = str_replace("&email&", $email, $message);

        if(mail($email, $_POST['subject'], $message, $headers)){
            echo "<font color='#FFFFB9'>{$index} Emailed: {$email}</font><br />";
        }else{
            $failure=true;
            echo "Oops, something went wrong on email index $index to $email<br>";
        }
    }
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting SMTP details for php mail () function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093976/setting-smtp-details-for-php-mail-function)

Comment: Why don't you use a library like SwiftMailer that handles all that difficult stuff for you?

Answer (score 0):

function do_email($msg = NULL, $sub = NULL, $to = NULL, $from = NULL, $bcc = NULL) {

```
        $config = array();
        $config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter";
        $config['mailpath'] = "/usr/bin/sendmail";
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
        $config['smtp_user'] = "yourgmail"; 
        $config['smtp_pass'] = "password";
        $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
        $config['mailtype'] = "html";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";


        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);      

        $this->email->from($from);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject($sub);            
        $this->email->message($msg); 
        $this->email->send();            

    }
```

Send your parameters to the above function.

Comment: Thank you. But i tried to do this but it's still not sending mails:
    <?php
       function do_email($msg = 'this is it', $sub = 'thank you', $to = 'jon@33yahoo.com', $from = 'eml@domain.com') {
            
            $config = array();
            $config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter";
            $config['mailpath'] = "/usr/bin/sendmail";
            $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
            $config['smtp_host'] = "mail.domain.com";
            $config['smtp_port'] = "26";
            $config['smtp_user'] = "eml@domain.com"; 
            $config['smtp_pass'] = "#Online123";

Comment: can you please post the error by debugging with the line below
echo $this->email->print_debugger(); exit();

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp2\www\Email_sender_SMTP\test2.php on line 26